# Querying mongodb via nodejs shows empty result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

1.I am trying to query the collection "radar_life_cycle" in database "teamautomation" via node below.js as below

2.I created the corresponding model
,connect to mongodb via mongoose is successful ,there are no errors but I get an empty list.

3. As you can see from output below posts is `[]` is empty list but I can see that there are records in the database,can anyone provide guidance on what could be wrong here?

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Radar_life_cycle = require("./models/radar_life_cycle");
const app = express();

mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb://username:password@1x.xxx.xxx.x:27017/wifiautomation"
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to database!");
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Connection failed!");
  });


app.get("/api/radars", (req, res, next) => {
 Radar_life_cycle.find({ orgRadar: "51918661" }).then(documents => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Posts fetched successfully!",
      posts: documents
    });
  });
});
```

**models/radar_life_cycle**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const radar_life_cycle_Schema = mongoose.Schema({
    Delivered: String,
    orgRadar: String,
    root_build: String,
    inserted_by: String,
    milestone: String,
    applicable_chipsets: [String],
    project_tag: String,
    gerrits:String,
    inserted_on:Date,
    SDK:String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('radar_life_cycle', radar_life_cycle_Schema);
```

OUTPUT:-

```
terminal$ nodemon server.js
[nodemon] 1.14.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
(node:17500) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
Connected to database!

{"message":"Posts fetched successfully!","posts":[]}
```

Expected output:-

```
{"message":"Posts fetched successfully!","posts":should include the corresponding records}
```

**Screenshot of document in database:**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have the documents in your database, as the code looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti - Yes,am sure there is a record in the database ,I updated my questio with a screenshot of it,what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried pass the collection name as third parameter (mongoose.model('radar_life_cycle', radar_life_cycle_Schema,'radar_life_cycle'))? Mongoose will add a 's' to the collection name and it may be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Schema in this way maybe is not doing a good reference to the collection

```
const { Schema } = require('mongoose');

const radar_life_cycle_Schema= new Schema({
    Delivered: String,
    orgRadar: String,
    root_build: String,
    inserted_by: String,
    milestone: String,
    applicable_chipsets: [String],
    project_tag: String,
    gerrits:String,
    inserted_on:Date,
    SDK:String
},
{
  collection: 'radar_life_cycle',
  timestamps: { createdAt: true, updatedAt: true },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('radar_life_cycle', radar_life_cycle_Schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/api/radars", (req, res, next) => {
 Radar_life_cycle.find({ orgRadar: "51918661" }).then(documents => {
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Posts fetched successfully!",
      posts: documents[0]
    });
  });
});
```

`find` method finds all documents in the database in this case it seems there is only one... If there are more you can update code above and access the documents using a loop.

Comment: If I do the way you suggested,the posts fields disappears completely...I only get `{"message":"Posts fetched successfully!"}`